# return same uid and email for all users in mybb

Tags: php, database, mybb

Hi i have a class login for check username and password of MYBB from external script its seems work but with small problem. for different users the result return same uid and email for all users (the first uid and email in mybb_users table). pleas how to fix that. thank you for help me.

```
class Login
{
    function CheckLogin( $username, $password )
    {           

$MySQL_Host = "localhost";
$MySQL_User = "root";
$MySQL_Pass = "";
$MySQL_DB = "";
$tbl_name = "";

    // Connect to server and select databse.
     mysql_connect("$MySQL_Host", "$MySQL_User", "$MySQL_Pass") or die(mysql_error());
    // echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";
     mysql_select_db("$MySQL_DB") or die(mysql_error());
    // echo "Connected to Database<br />";

        $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);          

        if( $result == false )
            return false;
//              fwrite($fh, $result);
//              fclose($fh);


        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
        // If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
        if($count==1){
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            global $mybb;
            if (md5(md5($row['salt']).md5($password)) == $row['password']){
            return array( 'uid' =>  $mybb->user['uid'] ,
                          'mail' => $mybb->user[ 'email' ],
                          'user' => $username
                        );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the username different for each users. Did you checked the DB? SELECT count(*) FROM tbl_name WHERE username='username'; Try this query in DB and tell me the output which your getting..

Comment: yes different username and now with   $sql="SELECT count(*) FROM tbl_name WHERE username='$username'";    i have incorrect username and/or password ?!

Comment: Did you run the query with PHP or just in DB? it should be done in DB alone.. and tell me the number of count your getting..

Comment: for all users  i have count=1  , and TomPHP what you mean pls say on my code tnx.

Comment: Try to print_r($row); and check what your getting. I run your script and it worked well but I modified few line so as to run in my system.

Comment: I have posted some code changes try it.

Comment: are you get different uid and email for different users? and with print_r($row); nothing!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30247/discussion-between-tomphp-and-user1973003)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your script like the following and try it.

```
return array( 'uid'  => $row['uid'] ,
              'mail' => $row['email'],
              'user' => $username
            );
```

I think this will work.